# some problems with c and c++ header file

Tags: c++, header-files

I have a confusing problem in using c functions in c++ class functions.

I have a class named `A` which is defined in `A.h` and implemented in `A.cpp`. And also I have `B.h` and `B.c` which has declared and implemented some functions.

Inside `A` functions I have called functions which are defined in `B.h` and `B.c` (there is no class `B`), I think this is a usual stuff but I get compiler error which says `Unresolved reference` or something else which pointing to the functions of `B`.

I have `#include "B.h"` at the start of `A.cpp` and, my compiler is GCC under Linux (opensuse 12.3), and I am sorry that I can not show you the codes because of copyright.

This is a confusing to me, I am not a C++ pro but I know the way that C++ header and source files working together, so just I am asking for help if someone have similar experience about this.

Thanks

Comment: C++ generates different symbols to those produced by C. Hence the need to use `extern "C"` as outlined below because this instructs the `g++` compiler to create C-style symbols for later linking. See the [Wikipedia article on Name Mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) for further information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "B.h";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile B.c as well as as include its functions

```
gcc -Wall A.cpp B.c -o my_prog
```

If you're doing that, make sure to add the following guard to B.h to avoid [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Handling_of_C_symbols_when_linking_from_C.2B.2B) of the C functions

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* declare your C functions here */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate header --> S.h, include function()'s of both A.c and B.c in it.. and include it wherever you want to..

or

For a list of C standard C headers (stdio, stdlib, assert, ...), prepend a c and remove the .h. For example stdio.h becomes cstdio.

```
For other headers, use

extern "C"
{
  #include "other_header.h"
}
```